# Custom sort function in BigQuery

Tags: javascript, sql, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

Is there a way to pass a comparison function to sort by a column in BigQuery? I am fine, if required, using a SQL or JS udf. This would be similar to something like Javascript's [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) function, returning a -number, 0, or +number depending on if the first value is less than or equal to the second value.

This would allow doing something like:

```
const comparisonFunction = (val1, val2) => ...
MyValues.sort(comparisonFunction)
```

For example, if I have the following data:

```
with tbl as (
  select "date" val union all 
  select "time" union all 
  select "number"
)
select * from tbl order by comparisonFunction(tbl.val)
```

And for arguments sake, let's say the comparison function is something like:

```
const RANK_MAP = {"number": 1, "time": 2, "date": 3}
function comparisonFunction(val1, val2) {
    return RANK_MAP[val1] - RANK_MAP[val2];
}
```

Note that I want this signature (or something like it). I'm **not** looking for 'converting this into an inline sql function' with something like:

```
with tbl as (
  select "date" val union all 
  select "time" union all 
  select "number"
)
select
  tbl.val,
  case tbl.val
    when 'number' then 1
    when 'time' then 2
    when 'date' then 3
  end rank
from tbl
order by rank
```

How could this be done with a udf function similar to the js approach above?

Comment: Can you please provide the your comparison function. Do you only want to use the localeCompare ?

Comment: @Samuel just sent you a comment to your answer.

Comment: What is the objective here? Do you want to transfer the sorting logic to a JavaScript function? Does it have to use `.sort(a, b)` to compare two values? Could the function simply translate x to y (`number` becomes 1) and then order by does the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery introduced [collations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/collation-concepts) to enable sorting independantly of the lower or upper-case. However, the language specified sorting is not yet available.

For your example, you showed already the possibility to replace each string by a pseudo value and to sort by it. This solutions is good, because it scales in parallel.

If you want to use the JavaScript sort function, the UDF is capable of doing so. However, your dataset should not extend several hundreds rows. All strings are combined in the table `helper` to an array. This array is sorted in the UDF. Then the sorted array is joined back to the main table and the offset of the array `sort_by` is the column you want to sort the table by.

```sql
create temp function sortme(MyValues array<string>)
returns array<string>
language js as
"""
fct1 = (a,b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', { sensitivity: 'base' }) ;
const RANK_MAP = {"number": 1, "time": 2, "date": 3};
function fct2(val1, val2) {
    return RANK_MAP[val1] - RANK_MAP[val2];
}
MyValues.sort(fct2)
return MyValues
""";

with tbl as (
  select "date" val union all 
  select "time" union all 
  select "number"
),
helper as (
  Select sortme(array_agg(distinct val)) sorted from tbl
  )

select * from tbl 
left join (select val, sort_by from helper,unnest(helper.sorted) as val with offset sort_by) using(val)
order by sort_by
```

Comment: that's quite a wonderful solution, really appreciate that. Though using the toArray and then unnesting gives a huge performance hit. For example, here is a query using a 100M multiplier on the table size -- https://gyazo.com/079442836e3a9b3801fb768f5ab000b5. I wonder if there is another way to do that without `array_agg`...`unnest` ?

Comment: Here's a slight improvement (also a lot of the time was returning all the results without a limit) -- `select val, sort_by from tbl, helper, unnest(helper.sorted) as valx with offset sort_by where val=valx order by sort_by limit 1000`.